# What is the angle made at the center by 7th and 23rd meeting points?

Tags: geometry

Two runners start running in opposite directions along a circular path from the same point simultaneously. Their speeds are 9m/sec and 6 m/sec. What is the angle made at the center by 7th and 23rd meeting points (in degrees)?

I am able to draw 5 meetings like this:

[image]

Drawing about 23 meetings and finding angle accurately is the part where I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

When the slower runner makes two circles, the fastest makes three.

Answer (score 0):

Since the speed of the runners is constant, you know that there is always the same time difference $T$ (in sec) between two consecutive meetings.

If $P$ is the perimeter, you have $P = 9T + 6 T = 15 T$.

So, for the angles you have

$360^° = \frac 9{15}360^° + \frac 6{15}360^°$

So, you have an angular shift between two consecuitive meetings of

$$\frac{6}{15}360^° =144° \mbox{ clockwise}$$

Now, just multiply correspondingly (and reduce by multiples of $360^°$ accordingly).